# Inserting component on click between grid rows

Tags: css, angular

I have a grid of items and when I click on one of them I want to show another component that takes all the width on the row under the clicked item.

Here is a picture of what I want to achieve
[image]

I have a button-list-component which contain a button-component that display my items with an ngFor.
When I click on an item the size-selection-component is shown with a ngIf.

My problem is that if I have the size-selection-component in the button-list-component, it append at the end of the grid, and if I have this new component in the button-component then it only takes the width of the column containing the clicked item.

If I put it in position absolute I can make it the width of the container but then the following items won't go down.

Here is a piece of my code

button-list

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <app-button *ngFor="let button of buttons;" [button]="button" (buttonClicked)="onButtonClicked($event)">
    </app-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(250rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10rem;
  place-items: start center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 10rem;
}
```

button

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="product-col">
        <h2 class="product_title" (click)="onButtonClicked()">{{button.Caption}}</h2>
        <img class="product_img" [src]="picture" alt="" (click)="onButtonClicked()">
        <span class="product_price" *ngIf="button.Price && button.Price != '0'">{{button.Price / 100 | currency}}</span>
    </div>
</div>

<app-size-selection-button-list *ngIf="isSizeSelectionOpen"></app-size-selection-button-list>
```

How would it be possible to achieve that ? Maybe there is a solution in CSS or maybe another way to insert my component in the grid of items that would work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to append the div, you can create it and hide it, when user hover over the item div, you show it and set its child tag's innerHTML to whatever you need, like this

```html
<body>
    <p onmouseover="show();"></p>AA</p>
    <div style="width:100%">
        <div style="width:33%">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div style="width:33%">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div style="width:33%">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="blah" style="display:none">
        <!-- whatever here -->
    </div>
<script>
    function show() {
        var b=document.getElementById("blah");
        b.style.display="block";
        // Change some innerHTML of elements inside the blah div here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Actually i'm not having trouble to show the new component I do it with the ngIf, I'm having trouble showing it on the next row following the clicked item like in the picture. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry for my late response but i'm quite not getting what your exact problem is. You mean the div is not showing in the next row? if it's so, add display:block to the div on the div you're having problems to show